# How can you restrict the mouse to a fullscreen electron app?

Tags: javascript, electron, mouse

I'm building a game in electron that requires the mouse and is to be played in full-screen.

For people with dual-monitors I don't want the mouse 'leaving' the game area without an alt-tab or similar.

I've tried this:

```
    canvas.requestPointerLock();
```

Which works to an extent but it removes the pointer entirely. I can't find a way to just restrict the mouse cursor to the active window.

Answer (score -1):

The canvas object should be the game area

var canvas = document.getElementById("**game_area**");

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("game_area");

 canvas.requestPointerLock();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but I tried that but it just removes to cursor entirely rather than restricts it to the canvas area.

Comment: U passed the correct id and id not duplicating in entire app also,right?

Comment: Yes there's only a single canvas and it has the same height and width and the screen. Firing this just removes the cursor